# Primeiro e segundo parâmetro no replaceState

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde!

Pra que serve o primeiro parâmetro no `window.hostory.replaceState()`

Por exemplo, nos exemplos que eu vi, eles sempre passam um objeto vazio...

Poderiam explicar exatamente como funciona este método?

Ja no segundo me pede o title, mas quando altero esse titulo nada acontece, o título da página continua o mesmo, pra que serviria então?

```
window.history.replaceState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente o primeiro parâmetro do método window.hostory.replaceState(), serve para passar alguma informação pelo estado do historico, acessando history.state você terá o objeto passado no parâmetro.
O método replaceState funciona de forma similar ao pushState, só que ao invés de adicionar a entrada atual do histórico ele modifica ela.
O uso básico desse método, seguindo o exemplo desse site -> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/History_API

1 -Suponha que você esta na página https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/History_API

2 - Você vai adicionar ou modificar a entrada atual do historico

```
const stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

3 - Ao navegar para outra página, como por exemplo - https://www.google.com.br/ e clicar na seta para voltar para o site developer.mozilla.org, você será redirecionado para o endereço informado no terceiro parâmetro do pushState(nesse caso "bar.html") e acessando 
history.state você terá o seu objeto stateObj.

O replaceState irá alterar as informações do registro atual, se fossemos usar o replaceState e colocasse outras informações ele iria sobreescrever os dados do nosso history.pushState.

Isso foi oque eu entendi lendo o https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/History_API, espero ter ajudado